# Append previous from values in java class using StringBuffer

Tags: java, javascript, stringbuffer

i have a textarea in a form where the user can enter their commands. I am retrieving this command in my java class.

```
Map<String, String[]> params = ActionContext.getParameters();
    for(String key: params.keySet()){
        value = params.get(key);
    }
val = value[0];
```

After every sumbit the form gets refresh. I need to display back to the user all the previously entered commands. But i am unable to append the values. after every submit the value of **val** also is getting refreshed. i am using Stringbuffer to append these values.
how could i do this using javascript?

Comment: can't you use your session?

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: have a session variable and append the command to it when you submit the form

Comment: is there any ohter way than using sessions?

Comment: i tried using session... the values get refreshed when the page is refreshed...

Comment: make sure to handle that when you are dealing with session variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320876/how-to-prevent-reexecute-action-when-refresh-in-jsp
and read this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059712/how-to-create-a-jsp-variable-that-does-not-reset-on-page-reload